# Output waveform of an SMD crystal oscillator

Tags: oscillator, waveform

I am going to setup lwIP on `STM32f107RCT6` with `DP83848` PHY device. The green LED of `RJ000002` magjack is turned on and solid and the orange one is blinking. However, I have not been successful to run ST ECHO TCP Server example on my own board. I started debugging from any point. Now correct function of `HX0-36A 50.000 MHz` (SMD crystal oscillator) is open to question for me. Its output waveform is:

[image]

(DC offset around 1.5V and VPP about 900mV)

Does it output correctly?
If it works fine why in its datasheet it is mentioned that:

Output Voltage:
VOH = 90% VDD Min  = 2.97V Min
VOL  = 10% VDD Max = 0.33V Max

The waveform of VDD voltage given at Pin 4 as power supply:

[image]

I edited my post based on *Justme's* answer:
With 10x mode and BW limit off the result is:

[image]

which is not matched with values provided in the datasheet (VOH = 2.97V).
[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lq2qw7z5sjgxy1a/Alarming.rar?dl=0) is my project (PDF file included).

Comment: No, that isn't correct. What is the capacitance of your probes? It looks like you're missing some decoupling capacitors (the datasheet recommends 10nF).

Comment: @BeB00 my probe is `GTP-100B-4`. In its datasheet it is declared that `Note: 0.01uF bypass capacitor should be placed between V (Pin4) and GND
(Pin2) to Minimize power supply line noise` which I took it into consideration in my designed schematic.

Comment: Oh sorry, I completely missed it on the left. Are you measuring the waveform in circuit? It's possible that the combined capacitance of the probe and the driven circuit is too high for it (it lists the typical load as 15pF). What does your power supply look like on the oscilloscope (measured at the pin, preferable with a ground tip probe)?

Comment: Also the oscilloscope being used by me is `GDS-1102A-U`

Comment: I added the image illustrating how the power supply looks like on the oscilloscope .

Comment: What happens if you remove the pull-up resistor? If that doesnt have any effect, I'm not sure what could be wrong apart from either the output being loaded too much, or the IC being broken. Maybe someone else can provide more insight

Comment: can you please tell me what shape the output signal is supposed to have? And also can you please make me aware of why you needed to observe the power supply voltage?

Comment: I picked another oscillator and put it out of my board alone and with a higher performance oscilloscope (200MHz)  the result is repeated! even without any pull-up resistor.

Comment: Are the probes in 1x or 10x mode? Is the scope bandwidth limit on or off?

Comment: @Justme, 1x mode and BW limit is off.

Comment: Where does the oscillator output goes to? PHY chip and MCU? To which pins on PHY and MCU? Can you post the schematics?

Comment: ...and board layout, and a photo of the actual board. Do you have any other high frequency clock that you can look at with the scope?

Comment: I attached my project.

Comment: When measuring any hf signals with an oscilloscope, you should always be using 10x mode (really, you should use 10x mode for everything unless you have a good reason not to)

Comment: Why not show the project in form that anyone can open? I would not even know what software that is made with.

Comment: Altium PCB Project. Ok, I will include schematic PDF file.

Comment: Are you sure PA1 is properly configured? Also, it seems very unusual that going from 1x->10x would cause the signal dc bias to decrease. Increasing might be understandable, but not decreasing.

Comment: @BeB00, please notice that, as I mentioned before, I put the oscillator out of the board alone to get rid of peripheral stuff and the result was the same. So configuration of PA1 is not likely to be questioned.

Comment: I see, sounds like it might just be broken then, not sure what other steps you can perform, unless its the wrong part number and requires a different voltage